# How to restrict file upload size limit based on file type in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess, is it possible to restrict the php file upload size limit based on type of file ?

For example, the maximum upload limit for images is 2 MB and maximum upload limit for PDF and DOC is 10 MB.

Comment: I don't actually think you can, you could check the file once it is uploaded of course but not before.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive for this. However, to quote:

> Implementations of the `PUT` method will require a value at least as large as any representation that the server wishes to accept for that resource.

You can set this to 10Mb to have Apache cut off any request which is surely too large, and then further test and filter within your script. This directive is mostly used to prevent denial-of-service attacks. Without this directive, Apache will gladly accept the entire file before it ever reaches your script, so users could be uploading 100Gb files before being told that it's too long.

This directive will not peek into the body of the request, though, so you can't filter on file type with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size limit and set types allowed but I don't believe you can join the two.

Comment: Do you have sources or a rationale for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you can define and restrict file size in **.htaccess** by using following :

```
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
```

Answer (score -1):

One method to help protect your server against DOS attacks involves limiting the maximum allowable size for file uploads. Here, we are limiting file upload size to 10240000 bytes, which is equivalent to around 10 megabytes. For this rule, file sizes are expressed in bytes.  Note: this code is only useful if you actually allow users to upload files to your site.

LimitRequestBody 10240000

Comment: please can u explain why negative reputation